# syslog forwarding

Tags: solaris, syslog

I'm using Solaris and have an application that writes to a log file 
`/app/data/log/foo_log.021118`.

Am I able to use syslog to forward that specific log file to a remote server?

Should I put something like

```
*.*/app/data/log/foo_log.021118       @remoteserver
```

in my `/etc/syslog.conf` ?

Cheers

Comment: I don't know what syslog program Solaris provides, but if it is rsyslog and a relatively recent version of it then you can use module `imfile`, see my answer to a similar question  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402159/119298).

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no.

Since your application is not using syslog to begin with, syslog has no way to intercept that data. The application would need to be reconfigured to use syslog instead of log files.

Alternatively, you could use the [`logger` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/logger-1b.html) to post-hoc send the log file via syslog:

```
logger -f /app/data/log/foo_log.021118
```

where you could then configure appropriate facility/priority pairs in /etc/syslog.conf (and then use `-p that-facility.that-priority` in the call to logger).  You would probably want to send the log file via logger *after* the application has finished writing to it; the timestamp implies a daily log file (2 Nov 2018, I'm assuming, based on today's date), so you could set up a job to send yesterday's log file.